# How to get logs of tx done in unit tests using programtest crate

Tags: transactions, program-test, unit-test, bankclient

So was doing some e2e testing using ProgramTest Create where we normally use the `process_transaction` api to execute tx but i was looking for a function which returned a signature or logs so i could implement some custom logic with log parsing
came across on a certain API

```
process_transaction_with_preflight_and_commitment_and_context( &mut self,
        ctx: Context,
        transaction: Transaction,
        commitment: CommitmentLevel,)
```

cant seem to understand where do i provide the context type from ?

Answer (score 1):

Nvm Context is retrieved via tarpc crate

Comment: consider elaborating by adding example code for future users interested in the answer to better understand how this is a solution